# FastAPI restrict valid path names at run time

Tags: fastapi

I know that FastAPI can [restrict valid path names using a class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class) that inherits from Enum, but this seems to mean that I must know the valid path names at design time.

But what if I only know the restricted list of valid paths at run time, using a function? And that function's results may change periodically. I want to restrict queries to those path names only but since the above uses a preformed class definition, and not an instance of the class, I don't see how I can make the valid path Enum change at runtime.

Is there a way for path name restrictions for an endpoint to be changed at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well everything is possible, you could for instance copy the values to a new Enum.. It's not very pretty, but the docs generator should pick up the changes if you make sure ModelName is reassigned globally

```
def new_enum(current_enum, names: List[str]):
    values = names

    for item in current_enum:
        names.append(item.name)
        values.append(item.value)

    return enum.Enum(current_enum.__name__, dict(zip(names, values)))


class ModelName(str, Enum):
    alexnet = "alexnet"
    resnet = "resnet"
    lenet = "lenet"


ModelName = new_enum(ModelName, ['foo', 'bar'])
```